# Mysql Rebooting replicated Master / Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, reboot

OS Debian 7
Mysql 5.5 replicated Master / Slave

I have updated the kernel on the master and slave and wish to reboot both servers.

Can someone advise on the correct procedure?

I thought this may be correct:

**On mysql slave:**
STOP SLAVE;
FLUSH TABLES;

**From OS on slave:**
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

I would reboot both servers at this point and then after the system has booted:

**On mysql slave (the mysql daemon is configured to start on boot):**

START SLAVE;

But I have heard that it may not work post Mysql 5.1.

Looking for advise.
Thank you
Rick

Answer (score 0):

I took my original advise, and it worked.

On mysql slave: STOP SLAVE; FLUSH TABLES;

From OS on slave: /etc/init.d/mysql stop

I would reboot both servers at this point and then after the system has booted:

On mysql slave (the mysql daemon is configured to start on boot):

START SLAVE;